# cupy_backends.cuda.libs.curand.CURANDError: CURAND_STATUS_INITIALIZATION_FAILED

Tags: cupy

When I run `cupy.random.seed(123)`, the error below occurred.

```
>>> cupy.random.seed(123)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/youngjoo/Documents/Elevation_ws/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cupy/random/_generator.py", line 1255, in seed
    get_random_state().seed(seed)
  File "/home/youngjoo/Documents/Elevation_ws/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cupy/random/_generator.py", line 1287, in get_random_state
    rs = RandomState(seed)
  File "/home/youngjoo/Documents/Elevation_ws/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cupy/random/_generator.py", line 57, in __init__
    self._generator = curand.createGenerator(method)
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/libs/curand.pyx", line 95, in cupy_backends.cuda.libs.curand.createGenerator
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/libs/curand.pyx", line 99, in cupy_backends.cuda.libs.curand.createGenerator
  File "cupy_backends/cuda/libs/curand.pyx", line 88, in cupy_backends.cuda.libs.curand.check_status
cupy_backends.cuda.libs.curand.CURANDError: CURAND_STATUS_INITIALIZATION_FAILED
```

I'm using Jetson AGX Orin Developer Kit.
Jetpack version is 5.1.2, CUDA version is 11.6.55, cuDNN version is 8.6.0.166, cupy version is cupy-cuda11x==12.3.0.
My OS is ubuntu 20.04.

How can I solve it?